Error 1324: [Version] section should specify PnpLockdown=1 to prevent external apps from modifying installed driver files
Gravité Code    Description Projet  Fichier Ligne   État de la suppression  Détails
Erreur  1324    [Version] section should specify PnpLockdown=1 to prevent external apps from modifying installed driver files.  kernel_socket_server    C:\Users\souln\Desktop\kernel_socket_server-master\kernel_socket_server\kernel_socket_server.inf    5       

I don't know how to fix the error, I've already made drivers and I get this error all the time

What do you specify for PnpLockdown in the Version section of the INF file?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/inf-version-section

Welcome to StackOverflow, @souleau!  I noticed this question when reviewing questions that might need additional details and/or context to help them get good answers, and indeed, I think this is a question that would benefit from a bit more introductory context, and/or detail about what exactly you're trying to do when you get the error.  (I'm not a Windows person, so maybe I just wouldn't know anyway, but... I'm not even sure what context is, so hard to say.)  Also, it might be helpful to temporarily set your locale to get English error messages, since the rest of your question is in English.

@lindes  I understand where you're coming from and your cause is noble, but this particular subject is an area of really technical black magic in the bowels of windows driver setup that very few people have any idea about. If you are one of those rare few who understand the question, then you don't need any more context. I'm not suggesting that other questions don't need help, but in this case explaining what he's doing wouldn't help if you don't already know some black magic.

@stu - I respectfully disagree, at least in part.  While yes, it wouldn't help me know the answer, it might help me understand what's being asked enough to somehow be useful.  At the very least, it would have helped me understand how to vote in the moderation task -- and, it's potentially useful to just have someone have that approach when asking questions about anything, in general, anywhere, so, I think it's still useful advice, especially to give to a user who's clearly new to the site.

yes it is useful advice, I'm just suggesting that in this particular case only, providing more context puts more burden on the asker without really supplying any value to the few people who could help answer, because if you don't already know the black magic or something about it, yes, the question won't make much sense, but there's no hope of being able to help with an answer, that's the only point I was trying to make, I wasn't trying to invalidate your argument.

OSR (bless them) has an explanation of this:
https://www.osr.com/blog/2021/10/08/should-i-set-pnplockdown1/
Basically you get the warning because microsoft really wants you to set
PnpLockdown = 1

in the [Version] section of your inf file.
Apparently what it does is lock down the acls to your driver file so it's really hard to delete or rename (protect against malware). I think the  "TrustedInstaller" user becomes the owner of the file.
Once you set PnpLockdown = 1 and install a sys file, it's very hard to delete.
So far all I've found that works is
takeown  /f C:\Windows\System32\drivers\<yourdriver>.sys
icacls C:\Windows\System32\drivers\<yourdriver>.sys /grant administrators:f /t

and this is all assuming your driver is not in use, then you can delete it.
